# Multitasking in iPhone 4,"application does not run in back ground" option in Xcode 3.2 info.plist

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, multitasking, info.plist

In Xcode 3.2 in INFO.PLIST we have option **"application does not run in back ground"** when we check this box and run the application in iPhone 4 ...every minimization leads to exiting of app.

**Doesn't this violate concept of Multi Tasking in iPhone 4?** because every time we minimize the application the application restarts.

**Can multi tasking be removed for iphone 4?** which means i am changing device behavior, which i feel is changing device properties(HIG guide line says should not
) , Isn't it a rejection risk?

Comment: What happens if you do not check that checkbox? The wording "does *not* run in background" suggests that this plist flag is working exactly as it is supposed to.

Comment: If we don't check this box then u can minimize the app , u can browse through other apps and can later open the minimized app and access the screen/page from where u minimized without restarting.

Comment: Then the purpose of that plist flag is to disable multi-tasking for your app. If you want to have a multi-tasking app, do not check that checkbox.

Comment: u mean multi tasking is not compulsory in iphone 4? i assumed its a mandatory HIG guideline not to change default device behaviour.

Comment: Which, I guess means that the answer to your question is "yes" `:)` checking that box will violate the multi-tasking concept for your app, if you choose to do so.

Comment: No, it is not compulsory. If you want to support multi-tasking, you can. It is highly recommended, since it benefits the user in most cases, but you are completely free to have your app avoid multi-tasking altogether.

Comment: One of the banking apps that I use does this. If I minimize the app, it logs me out of my account and goes back to the login screen when I re-open it. Perfectly reasonable `:)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I feel that preventing an app from supporting multitasking doesn't violate Apple's guidelines. Apple should have felt it too.  If you application doesn't actually need to run in background, you can very well prevent it by enabling *"application does not run in back ground"* key. I bet, Apple won't sue you.

**Why would Apple even add a feature that violates its own rules?**

Comment: Apple says application should not have memory leaks..but some times their own frame works have memory leaks..So...even **Apple violates its own rules** ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what your actual question is (I honestly don't understand it), but the box is specifically meant to disable any kind of background running of your application. If, for whatever reason, you do **not** wish your app to stay alive in the background, check that box.

Keep in mind, that if you really want to start a background threat after your app is suspended, you have to manually do that (and of course disable the option). Staying alive in the background without any specific action from the developer only means you will be kept alive in the background as long as the system allows you to (i.e: if system resources run low, your app will be killed unless you start a background threat, which buys you more time).

If you check that box, you will be killed no matter what. Could be helpful if you do not wish to handle any background states and it is fine (or even wanted) for your application to restart every time the user starts it.

Comment: My question is Multi tasking in iPhone 4 means running many applications parallely ,so when we check this box we cannot run this application parallely with other apps, doesn't this violate multi tasking concept?

Comment: Apple isn't enforcing any multi tasking (btw, leaving this box enabled doesn't allow you to multi task by default!!) it only allows you to deliver this service to your customers (more or less the illusion of multi tasking). So they do not violate their own rules, because they have none. And as a part of a multi tasking concept there is also single tasking (without single tasking; no multi tasking) so being able to disable multi tasking does also not violate any concepts. I think you are worried over nothing :-)